# es posible ignorar un MsgBox en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb

soy nuevo y estoy un poco atorado con una cuestión, ¿ Es posible ignorar un MsgBox o que solo aparezca 1 vez?, lo que pasa es que tengo un try catch y me arroja una advertencia en un MsgBox, lo que necesitó es que solo lo haga 1 vez y continúe porque actualmente me envía en un MsgBox el error cada 2 registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sobre que codigo? porque ese codigo solo muestra 1 messageBox.. y si podrias, tranquilamente, si agregas una bandera que aclare si lo mostro o no. Pero dejar de mostrar errores es una muy mala idea.

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Answer (score 1):

No existe ninguna función "mágica" o "switch" o "llámale como quieras". La única opción posible es que definas una variable de tipo Boolean y la inicialices a True. Cuando muestres el MessageBox la estableces a False. Y lógicamente solo muestras el MessageBox cuando la variable es True.